# Proof Verification: Uniqueness of Function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

[image]

Would this be a correct proof? This was the only way I could think of to show that w and v had to be the same since I did try expanding things out and just ran into dead ends.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that you are required to show that this property of $f$ forces $f$ to be of this exponential form. Have you given that any thought?

Comment: Well, I think the given property does imply an exponential form of $f$, but does it necessarily imply that $w$ must be unique?

Comment: See My answer below, I believe that you're misinterpreting the question. I hope the answer helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $f(0+0)=f(0)=f(0)f(0)$, by the property we are given...Hence $f(0)=0, \text{or $1$}$
If $f(0) = 0$, then $\forall x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, we must have $f(x)=f(0+x)=f(0)f(x)=0,$ So this would be written uniquely as $f(x) = \exp(-i\langle 0, x \rangle)$.

Then we are left with the case that $f(0)=1$
Let $\{ e_1, ..., e_n\}$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$.
Note that $f(2e_j)=f(e_j)^2$ and proceeding by induction, $f(me_j)=f(e_j)^m$ for any $m \in \Bbb{R}$. And further, $f(e_j) = f(m\frac{e_j}m) = f(\frac{e_j}m)^m$ and so $f(\frac{e_j}m) = f(e_j)^{(\frac{1}m)}$.
So finally for any rational $q \in \Bbb{Q}, f(qe_j) = f(e_j)^q$ and continuity gives us exactly that $\forall r \in \Bbb{R}\; f(re_j) = f(e_j)^r$.

If for any basis element, $e_j$, we had that $f(e_j)=0$ then for any element $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ with non-zero coefficient of $e_j$ then say $x = a_1e_1 + a_2e_2 + ... + a_ne_n$, with $a_j \in \Bbb{R}\; \forall j \in \{1, ..., n\}$, then $f(x) = f(e_1)^{a_1}f(e_2)^{a_2}...f(e_n)^{e_n}=0$-from $e_j$ term. And then by continuity of $f$ we are back to $f$ constantly $0$ as above in first case.

So we can presume that $f(e_j) \ne 0$ for any basis element $e_j$.
So we let, $f(e_j) = A_j\exp(-ik_j)$, for some constants $A_j, k_j \in \Bbb{R}$.
So $f(a_je_j) = A_j^{a_j}\exp(-ia_jk_j)$. Boundedness then gives us that $A_j = 1$ for all $j \in \{1, ...,n\}$.

Then for any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n,\; x = a_1e_1 + ... + a_ne_n$, for unique scalars $a_1, ..., a_n \in \Bbb{R}$, so $$\begin{align} f(x) &=f(e_1)^{a_1}f(e_2)^{a_2}...f(e_n)^{a_n} \\
&=\exp(-ia_1k_1)\exp(-ia_2k_2)...\exp(-ia_nk_n) \\
&=\exp(-i(a_1k_1 + ... a_nk_n)) \\
&=\exp(-i\langle x, k \rangle)  \end{align}$$
Where $k \in \Bbb{R}^n$ is $k = (k_1, ..., k_n)$.
Note that any function defined this way satisfies the property that we require it to. And hence I feel that the question is asking you to show that this additive functional property implies that $f$ is of this exponential form.
The uniqueness part of it comes from the fact that now $k \in \Bbb{R}^n$ is uniquely determined by its values on the basis elements $\{e_1, ..., e_n\}$, so given an $f$ of this form, we have a unique such $k \in \Bbb{R}^n$.

I am hoping that this is in some way useful. If not good luck!!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I understand where I went wrong now, the thoroughness of you reply is appreciated! :)